# Можно ли скомпоновать наследника StatefulWidget и используемого им наследника State в один класс?

Tags: flutter, dart

Ниже приведён фрагмент кода из [урока по Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhiNcibEeTI):

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  const Home({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}



class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Не хотелось бы, чтобы было по 2 класса на 1 файл. Можно ли эти классы как-то скомпоновать в один?

Comment: Нельзя, и [в документации написана причина разделения](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview#widget-state).

Comment: Если класс стейта сам по себе не нравится, то можно использовать другие подходы к управлению состоянием - есть такие, которые позволяют все делать стейтлесс виджетами. Далеко ходить не надо, даже дефолтный provider позволяет напихать все состояние в один God-class подключаемый в основании дерева виджетов, и все тянуть из него (но это **очень** плохая идея, лучше так не делать). Сам использую GetX, но тут советовали слезать с него, объяснив тем что гетэкс начинает тупить и протекать по мере роста приложения (пока что не столкнулся с этим).

Comment: _«все делать стейтлесс виджетами»_ - поправка: почти все. Анимации, например, "ломаются" если перестраивать в билдере (потому что виджет при этом заменяется новым). Наверное, можно контроллер анимации вынести за пределы виджета, но это уже прям вообще страшные антипаттерны пошли, так что лучше мне перестать думать и печатать, пока нечаянно не сотворил врата в адъ :D

Comment: @yar85 Благодарю Вас за подробное объяснение! Мне даже трудно представить, сколько часов сбора информации оно сэкономило.